# wordpress mySQL query issues with numbers

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I'm having trouble recreating a query from straight mySQL to $wpdb compatible.

```
SELECT meta_value
    FROM `wp_postmeta`
    WHERE meta_key = 'review_rating'
      AND meta_value = 5
      AND post_id IN (118, 117, 116, 115, 114, 113, 112, 110, 109, 161)
```

When testing in Sequel Pro app it returns the correct number of posts that match the meta_value from the post_ids but when used in Wordpress it only returns "1"

Not sure what I'm doing wrong on including an integer/number into the SQL query. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: im surprised you are even getting results with the query as it is now. Are you sure you posted it correctly? Based on what you have here, you should only ever get multiple rows of 5

Comment: The `meta_value` field is _longtext_, so try query it accordingly: `AND meta_value = '5' `